# Parameters for Validator Model Driven (Reactive) Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I created a validation form using the model driven. 
This is my validator that checked if the email is well-formed.

```
static emailValidator(control) {

    if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
    }
  }
```

and I used it in this way:

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {


    //controlli campi della form

    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      'email': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]]
    });
```

Now, how can I pass a parameter, like a string, in my validator? For example I want that the email does not contain the string "abcd".

Thank you

Comment: Make validator function return a function, so that you can call it passing in value.

Comment: I did not understand. Please, Can you write me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just make a function that returns the validator function.

```
static emailValidator(match: string) {
  return function (control: AbstractControl) {
    // do validation here
  }
}
```

Usage

```
'email': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator(someValue)]]
```

Comment: Thank you, now it works! Another question if it is possible;
how can I use like input of my validator the value of another form build's attribute? For example:
`this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'surname': ['', Validators.required],
      'email': ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator(s)]]
});`
How can I put the surname's value inside the email's validator?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

 if (EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value)) {
             return null;  
        }
 else {
      return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
    }
```